# Reactjs - Can xterm.js have problem with webpack configuration?

Tags: reactjs, xtermjs

So far I am not able to properly integrate xterm.js with reactjs due to which my code breaks in production but works while development.

HELP !!!

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Terminal} from 'xterm';
import {FitAddon} from 'xterm-addon-fit';

const UITerminal = () => {
const term = new Terminal();
const fitAddon = new FitAddon();
term.loadAddon(fitAddon);

useEffect(() => {
let termDocument = document.getElementById('terminal')
if (termDocument) {
term.open(termDocument)
fitaddon.fit();
}
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
fitaddon.fit();
})
}, [])

return (<div id="terminal"></div>)

}
```

Below is the error response from production code. clearly it fails to import xterm

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 ReferenceError: Cannot access 'r' before initialization
at new m (96209.72626fc1cc862aea477a.bundle.js:1:165467)
at new b (96209.72626fc1cc862aea477a.bundle.js:1:159758)
at new M (96209.72626fc1cc862aea477a.bundle.js:1:57572)
at new r.exports.i.Terminal (96209.72626fc1cc862aea477a.bundle.js:1:294972)
at w (96209.72626fc1cc862aea477a.bundle.js:1:15994)
at zo (main.71e827eabc798023c129.bundle.js:1:1260000)
at Ws (main.71e827eabc798023c129.bundle.js:1:1333492)
at Wi (main.71e827eabc798023c129.bundle.js:1:1294411)
at Ui (main.71e827eabc798023c129.bundle.js:1:1294336)
at Pi (main.71e827eabc798023c129.bundle.js:1:1291367)
```

**UPDATE**

I have found out that it is happening because of my production webpack configuration but still the root cause is unidentified. please help in soughting this out. I am adding my development and production webpack config here.
Please note that the dev webpack config absolutely works fine if build with it and serve.

webpack.dev.js

```
const fqdn = "some.fqdn.com"
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack")
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const fs = require('fs');
const jsonFormat = require('json-format');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const jsonFromatConfig = {
  type: 'space',
  size: 4
}

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
var MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin')
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "naming.[name].contenthash.[contenthash].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build")
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin( {
        template: "./public/index.html",
        minify: {
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true
        }
      } ),
      new MinifyPlugin({}, {
        comments: false
    })
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minChunks: 3
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "naming.[name].contenthash.[contenthash].css" }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
          "css-loader" 
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Please read [the FAQ on asking questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't post code as a screenshot, it makes it much less likely that someone will check out your question. Also, looks like you're mixing up variable names — you define `fitAddon` but use a nonexistent `addonfit`.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you might use Xterm before its initialization,

You might find it useful to use [react-aptor](https://github.com/realamirhe/react-aptor) or the idea behind it to connect pure js packages like Xterm.js into react world.

```
import useAptor from 'react-aptor';

const initializer = (node, params) => {
  // user params for further configuration
  const terminal = new Terminal();
  term.open(node);
  return terminal;
}


const getAPI = (terminal, params) => {
  return () => ({ terminal })
}


const ReactXterm = (props, ref) => {
  const aptorRef = useAptor(ref, {
    getAPI,
    instantiate,
    /* params: anything */
  });

  return <div ref={aptorRef} />;
};
```

```
function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  const writeToTerminal = () => {
   ref.current.terminal?.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ');    
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactXterm ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={writeToTerminal}>write to terminal</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

###### Disclosure: I am the maintainer of react-aptor

Comment: If you're answering with a link to your own package, it's not a bad idea to disclose that you're the one who wrote it :)